# Update iframe live with contents of textarea using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to load an iframe with the contents of a text area, atm I have this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ce").html($("#som").val());
$("#som").keypress(function(){$("#ce").html($("#som").val());});
$("#som").keyup(function(){$("#ce").html($("#som").val());});
$("#som").keydown(function(){$("#ce").html($("#som").val());});
});

<div id="con">
    <textarea id="som"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="ce"></div>
```

As you can see I'm loading the info to a div that I for some reason just realized would not work because the user would easily be able to change the page if they enter HTML.  that is what I want, but I need it to send it to a iframe instead. I Googled for a while but I couldn't find what I needed.
 
  I am wanting it to stay short and simple like I had for the div based one that resembles how I have it setup if its possible. I don't need you to put the whole code together for me (although it would be nice) you could just help point me in the right direction and I would be happy, thanks in advance.

Comment: how you want to load an iframe with the contents of a textarea?
is the user going to type the URL of a website?

Comment: no its a live html editor, it will load the html,I know for sure its possible with plain js but I want a way to get it done using jquery